# Get the file with the oldest creation date in FTP SERVER

Tags: c#, ftp, ftp-client

I write the next code that give me a list with the files in /DocXML.

I want is to get the file with the oldest creation date. How I can do?

Thanks for all.

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ftp.DownloadFile(textBox1.Text, textBox7.Text);
    FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://192.168.47.1/DocXML");
    request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectory;
    request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");

    FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

    Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream);

    string names = reader.ReadToEnd();

    textBox12.Text = names; 
}
```

Comment: Can you post an example what `reader.ReadToEnd()` returns?

Comment: I return this `Nuevo - copia (2).txt`
`Nuevo - copia (3).txt`
`Nuevo - copia (4).txt`
`Nuevo - copia.txt`
`Nuevo.txt`

Comment: And do not ask the same question twice! [How can I download the oldest file of an FTP server?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30280333/850848)